# Inserir dados do DataSet em banco de dados

Tags: c#, dataset

Tenho o seguinte codigo:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

namespace TblCliente
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FbConnection fbConnectionPrincipal = new FbConnection
            {
                ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["strFirebirdPrincipal"].ToString()
            };
            FbConnection fbConnectionSecundaria = new FbConnection
            {
                ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["strFirebirdSecundaria"].ToString()
            };

            FbDataAdapter fbDataAdapterPrimario = new FbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM PRODUTO WHERE PRODUTO.CODPROD = '000399'", fbConnectionPrincipal);
            FbDataAdapter fbDataAdapterSecundario = new FbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM PRODUTO WHERE PRODUTO.CODPROD = '000399'", fbConnectionSecundaria);

            DataTable dataTableP = new DataTable();
            DataTable dataTableS = new DataTable();

            fbDataAdapterPrimario.Fill(dataTableP);
            fbDataAdapterSecundario.Fill(dataTableS);

            dataTableP.Merge(dataTableS);

            var Produto = dataTableP.AsEnumerable().Distinct();


            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Esse código trás resultados de duas base de dados distintas e inclusos em `DataSet` diferentes, apos isso fiz um `DataSet.Merge` e em cima dele foram retornados os valores distintos.
Como faco para incluir essas linhas distintas em um novo banco de dados ?

Comment: Abrindo uma nova conexão e fazendo o insert?

Comment: Essa nova conexao seria a fbConnectionSecundaria mesmo!

Comment: Então é só escrever o Insert utilizando a `fbConnectionSecundaria` mesmo...

Answer (score 1):

Se já tem toda a informação armazenada no `DataTable` então o necessário será inseri-la na base de dados:

```
private void InsertData(dynamic fbCon, string table, List<(string Field, dynamic Value)> parameters)
{
    string fields = string.Join(", ", parameters.Select(r => r.Field));
    string values = string.Join(", ", parameters.Select(r => $"@{r.Field}"));
    string sql = $"INSERT INTO {table}({fields}) VALUES({values})";

    FbCommand fbCom = new FbCommand(sql, fbCon);

    foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        fbCom.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter.Field, parameter.Value);

    fbCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Este método pode ser utilizado na generalidade dos casos, e a forma de o utilizar é algo deste género:

```
var list = new List<(string Field, dynamic Value)>();

list.Add((Field: "price", Value: 10));
list.Add((Field: "name", Value: "teste"));
list.Add((Field: "date", Value: DateTime.Today));

InsertData(null, "products", list);
```